# What is the order parameter of 2D generalized $XY$ model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, spin-models

I'm now studying the phase transition of 2D generalized XY model. This model considered here has a mixture with ferromagnetic and nematic-like interactions,

$$\mathcal{H}=-\sum_{\langle i j\rangle}\left[\Delta \cos \left(\theta_{i}-\theta_{j}\right)+(1-\Delta) \cos \left(q \theta_{i}-q \theta_{j}\right)\right],$$
where the the sum is over the nearest neighbors spins on a square lattice, $0 \leq \Delta \leq 1$, and $q$ is a positive integer. This model has three phases, paramagnetic(P), Ferromagnetic(F) and Nematic(N).

I am especially studying $q=3$ case. According to this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4442), the transition between N-P and F-P are Kosterlitz-Thouless universality class and N-F belong to the 3-states Potts universality class. The order parameter is defined as
 $m_{k}=\frac{1}{L^{2}}\left|\sum_{i} \exp \left(i k \theta_{i}\right)\right|$ , $ k= 1$ for 3-states Potts universality class and $k = 3$ for Kosterlitz-Thouless universality class. I can't understand why the order parameter is defined as $m_{k}$. Plese teach me.